# How do you jump backwards when hanging from a wall in Assassin's Creed 2 for the PC?

Tags: pc, assassins-creed-2

How in the heck do you jump backwards off the wall in Assassin's Creed 2 for the PC?

I press the high profile button <kbd>w</kbd> and then tap <kbd>space</kbd> and the direction I want to go and just keep falling off and never jumping the direction I want to go.  I've been trying for about an hour and am about ready to find the creators of this game...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

...I dont know why I couldn't find this answer anywhere online, I know this has to be a big problem for other people.  I finally got it after hiting every combination of buttons

to jump backwards off a wall, to the wall behind you:

press and hold the high profile (right mouse button) <kbd>w</kbd> and <kbd>s</kbd>, then
tap the <kbd>space</kbd>, presto chango

this seems so simple now and I feel like a fool for having issues..

Comment: Actually, you don't need to press any direction keys at all. Just press "jump" while holding "high profile", and you will jump straight backwards off the wall, every time, with no chance of screwing up because you pressed the wrong direction keys.

Comment: thats not true at all, and i have tried that

Comment: Hm, I know it works like that in Brotherhood and Revelations, at least. I'll double check in vanilla AC2 tomorrow on my 360. Might possibly be a PC/console difference.

Comment: Well...this question is Specifically for the PC, not the PS3 or xbox, as shown in the tags and the question title

Comment: I can verify *hammar* is correct. I am on a PC. The 180 degree jump / climb thing was screwing me up, especially with the weird camera angles one sometimes gets in tighter spaces. If you are holding down any keys besides the HIGH PROFILE key, Altair will tend to leap in unhelpful directions. So, just hold down your HIGH PROFILE key, and tap your LEGS key to jump. If there is a graspable object behind Altair, he will leap for it.

Answer (score 4):

The correct way to jump backwards is to hold high-profile (<kbd>RMB</kbd> by default) and hit jump (<kbd>Space</kbd> by default) without touching any movement keys.

Answer (score -1):

first Shift and tab space bar do jump backwards
to jump up and side ways, lets say you want to jump up to the right: hold down W+D tab space bar. W+A space bar is up to the left